# Tomcat installed folder access is denied on linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, installation

Please find below set of cmds & outputs
`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-38-218 opt]$ ls -al
total 9416
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    4096 Nov  7 13:52 .
dr-xr-xr-x 25 root root    4096 Nov  7 13:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 9625824 Sep  4 22:52 apache-tomcat-8.5.34.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    4096 Aug 11 01:26 aws
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-38-218 opt]$ sudo groupadd tomcatgrp`

**`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-38-218 opt]$ sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcatgrp -d /opt/tomcatfolder tomcatuser`**

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-38-218 opt]$ ls -al
total 9420
drwxr-xr-x  4 root       root         4096 Nov  7 13:53 .
dr-xr-xr-x 25 root       root         4096 Nov  7 13:16 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root       root      9625824 Sep  4 22:52 apache-tomcat-8.5.34.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x  5 root       root         4096 Aug 11 01:26 aws`

**`drwx------  2 tomcatuser tomcatgrp    4096 Nov  7 13:53 tomcatfolder`**

Now, when I run the cmd I am getting Permission denied as follows

`[ec2-user@ip-172-31-38-218 opt]$ cd /opt/tomcatfolder/`

`-bash: cd: /opt/tomcatfolder/: Permission denied`

Can you please help in resolving this above issue..?

I followed instructions of installing Tomcat from this link [how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7)

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are the `ec2-user`, but the directory is owned by `tomcatuser` and the permissions on the directory do now allow other users or groups to read it.

Try `sudo chmod 755 /opt/tomcatfolder/` and then `cd` into it.

That will add read and execute permissions to the directory.